# How to add a default bookmark (quick folder access) to all users?

Tags: nautilus, user-management

I have many users on my machine; I would like them to have in the bookmarks tab of the Nautilus a link to a specific folder e.g. `/home/shared-folder`. Is there a way I can change the default bookmarks (Recent, Starred, Home, Documents ... ) to include also this position without having to manually add it one by one?